# Facebook Feed Dialog with a video already uploaded in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dialog

I'm trying to do a Feed Dialog in Facebook with a video already uploaded in Facebook.

First, I tried putting in the 'source' param the URL of the video, extracting it with the json return by Graph Api. However, Facebook doesn´t support their own media URLs in this way.

My intention is to show the same effect when you click in "Share" in any video in you facebook profile, but I don't know how i can refer the video.

I don't find anything in the Facebook's developers documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking to the video page itself, like how you link to YouTube if you want to share a video. Facebook renders the YouTube player in the wall when you do this, so in theory it should do the same when you share a Facebook Video URL.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the option: "Embed this Video" . In the code that Facebook gives in this option, I can find the URL for the video (www.facebook.com/v/video_id), and this works fine in the feed dialog.

The problem was the URL given in the JSON.

Thanks